# Bluez/Python buffering causes laggy bluetooth connection

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, python-asyncio, bluez

I wrote a Python program that both reads and writes a L2CAP connection via a bluetooth socket (see example below) to talk to some hardware. However the code may want to do too much IO for the bluetooth adapter too handle, so I equipped it to handle laggy reads and writes by slowing down the `bar` loop if needed, as this is preferable to delay when responding to requests.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET, socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP)
sock.connect((bt_addr, bt_port))
sock.setblocking(False)

stall_loop = asyncio.Event()
stall_loop.set()

async def bar():
    while True:
        await stall_loop.wait()
        await loop.sock_sendall(generate_data(time.time()))
        await asyncio.sleep(maybe_to_small_delay)

async def foo():
    while True:
        await request = loop.sock_recv(sock, 400)
        stall_loop.clear()
        await loop.sock_sendall(generate_response(request))
        stall_loop.set()

asyncio.gather(foo, bar)
```

The problem however is that neither of these loops see any notable slowdown until `bar` freezes for seconds at a time.

I timed the execution of both loops using `time.time()` and execution time is mere milliseconds including the IO (except when `bar` freezes), but anything written by `foo` may only be sent with up to 15s of delay (as reported by `tshark` and comparing to the time python considers the write done)

The behavior I want is the write to only return once the data is actually transmitted in order to retain a responsive `foo` and a `bar` as close to the wanted speed as possible.

I assume the culprit is some kind of buffering policy that buffers a large amount of data until the buffer is full and then flushes it completely. How can I either disable this bahviour and/or limit the buffer size to e.g. 2 packets? I couldn't find documentaion on `ioctl` for bluez.

Versions:

- Raspbian on kernel 5.10.17-vl7+
- Python 3.7.3
- bluez 5.50

Comment: @ukBaz, I thought of that, but sadly they don't support bluetooth sockets. They all are wrappers around the [Opening Network Connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#id5) API which only supports `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6` and `AF_UNIX` using an additional function.

Comment: @ukBaz So you mean I should create the socket as above and then wrap it inside a `Stream` with a small buffer. Wouldn't that just create more lag, since the socket itself already lags and the Stream buffers aswell or do Streams have some knowledge about sockets I don't and configure the socket's buffering?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the buffering in Linux, the solution was to disable it:

```
client_itr.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 0)
```

Found this option today in the [GNU libc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Socket_002dLevel-Options.html).

I don't know why it decided to flush the buffer completely once it was filled up (which caused the `bar`-loop to freeze for a while), but without buffering behaviour is as expected: between `foo` receiving a request and it sending a reply are a maximum of 2 `bar` packets, even without the `Event`-locking.

Note however that without buffering the `sendall` only blocks until the data was send via bluetooth, not until it was acknowledged by the recipient. For that you would presumably have to lower the window size of L2CAP.